# how to read the connection string from App.config file by C#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I'm using this code to read the connection string from my app.config file but it always return a null value. My App.config file is under my project. Both methods are resulting null values:

```
public SqlConnection getConnection()
{
    try
    {
        // connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbConn"];

        connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConn"].ConnectionString;
        connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbConn"];
        sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);  

        sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    return sqlConnection;
}
```

This is my app.config file declaration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="dbConn" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
          connectionString="Data Source=VANYA\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;User  Id=sa;Password=123" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Does your project happen to be a *class library* project? Those do **not** actually use their own `app.config` file - you'll need to put your connection string into the **hosting application** (the main program or web app / web site) using your class library

Comment: marc_s ++ worked for me..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you please try

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="dbConn" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
          connectionString="Data Source=VANYA\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;User  Id=sa;Password=123" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="dbConn"  value="Data Source=VANYA\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;User  Id=sa;Password=123" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Then use the second method.

Make sure you select the App.Config file in the solution explorer and in the property window select `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy Always`. Now Build the application and try again.

[image: See the screenshot]

Answer (score 5):

I think your problem that you try to read connection string twice, first you do it right, and second time you do it wrong, so just remove second line:

```
connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConn"].ConnectionString;
sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
```

`ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` used to access `<appSettings>...</appSettings>` section of the config.

Comment: Your are overwriting connectionString by re-assigning it. Remove the 2nd assigment of connectionString and you will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You simple define connection string in one class and call that string.....

```
public class Connection
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Connection String
        /// </summary>
        public static string ConnectionString
        {
            get
            {
                return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConn"].ConnectionString;
            }
        }
    }

//Returning connction string
 sqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Connection.ConnectionString);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
connectionString=global::myProject.Properties.Settings.Default.myConnectionString
```